# Trying to prevent over-registration in class registration application

Tags: mysql, forms, coldfusion

We have a class registration form for a children's camp. I have been asked to ensure that registrations are limited to just the seats available.

When the form is submitted, I have code that checks to see if seats are available for all classes submitted. If seats are available, the registration is entered into the registrations table. If not, the user is returned to the class list to make new selections.

I have enclosed the code that checks the availability in a `CFLOCK`. My understanding was that `CFLOCK` would only allow one submission at a time to access the code within the lock. I have not used `CFLOCK` previously and so I may be using it inappropriately.

My problem is with simultaneous requests for the last available seat. I have tested the code with 5 simultaneous requests for the last seat several times and each time 3 of the 5 requests were successful.

I'm using ColdFusion 9 and MySQL 5 (MyISAM tables)

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

Here is the code that checks seat availability:

```
<!--- 3E Check Class availability and Submit or Re-Select --->
<!--- Class 1 availability --->

<cfif IsDefined('Class1') and Class1 neq ''>
    <cflock name="ClassAvail" timeout="10" throwontimeout="no" type="exclusive">
        <!--- Check number of registrations for Class 1 --->
        <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="Registrations1">
            Select Count(*) as Count From Registrations
            Where Class_ID = #Class1#
        </cfquery>
        <!--- Check number of seats for class 1 --->
        <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="ClassAvail1">
            Select Class, Class_Size from Classes
            Where ID = #Class1#
        </cfquery>
        <!--- Check for seat availability --->
        <cfif Registrations1.count GTE ClassAvail1.Class_size>
            <cfset Class1_Avail = 'False'>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset Class1_Avail = 'True'>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Class 2 availability --->
        <cfif IsDefined('Class2') and Class2 neq ''>
            <!--- Check number of registrations for Class 2 --->
            <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="Registrations2">
                Select Count(*) as Count From Registrations 
                Where Class_ID = #Class2#
            </cfquery>
            <!--- Check number of seats for class 2 --->
            <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="ClassAvail2">
                Select Class, Class_Size from Classes 
                Where ID = #Class2#
            </cfquery>
            <!--- Check for seat availability --->
            <cfif Registrations2.count GTE ClassAvail2.Class_size>
                <cfset Class2_Avail = 'False'>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset Class2_Avail = 'True'>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <!--- If Classes Available, Insert in Registrations --->
        <cfif (IsDefined('Class1_Avail') and Class1_Avail eq 'True') and (IsDefined('Class2_Avail') and Class2_Avail eq 'True')>
            <cfloop from="1" to="2" index="LoopCount">
                <cfif ISDEFINED("class#loopcount#")>
                    <cfset Class_ID = #ListGetAt(ClassChoice, #loopcount#)#>
                    <cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="AddRegistration">
                        Insert into Registrations (Child_ID, Class_ID) Values(#Session.Child_ID#, #Class_ID#)
                    </cfquery>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
            <cflocation addtoken="no" url="Thanks.cfm">
        </cfif>
    </cflock>

    <!--- Classes not available --->
    <cfif (IsDefined('Class1_Avail') and Class1_Avail eq 'False') or (IsDefined('Class2_Avail') and Class2_Avail eq 'False')>
        <cfset ClassChoice = "">
        <cfset Class1 = "">
        <cfset Class2 = "">
        <div style="display: block; z-index: 1000; border: #F00 thick solid; background-color: #FFF; position: absolute; top: 220px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 3px 5px #999999; padding:20px">
            We're sorry, but one or more of your choices are no longer available.<br />
  Please make your selections again.<br />
        </div>
        <cfif Class1_Avail eq 'False'>
            <h3><cfoutput>#classavail1.class# is no longer available.</cfoutput></h3>
            <br/>
        </cfif>
        <cfif Class2_Avail eq 'False'>
            <h3><cfoutput>#classavail2.class# is no longer available.</cfoutput></h3>
            <br/>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: I noticed in your check for class availability to "insert in registrations" you are checking that both `Class1_Avail` **AND** `Class2_Avail` are set to true. Is that correct?  Or does there only need to be availability in one of the classes and therefore you should be using **OR** instead?

Comment: you should be using `cfqueryparam` and you can also just use `<cfset Class1_Avail = false>` to set it as a boolean rather than a string.

Comment: What is Autocommit setting on all sessions? What is isolation level on all sessions?

Comment: Both selected classes must be available to complete the registration. Thanks Matt, I'll make note of those suggestions. Marcus, I not set anything for Autocommit or issolation level for the sessions.

Comment: Let me put it another way. Is any of this wrapped in `cftransaction`?

Comment: No. I have not tried that solution yet.

Comment: Keep in mind it is more just wrapping queries in a transaction. You must also use the appropriate isolation level to correctly block other threads. That said ... does MyISAM even support transactions? Some brief searching suggests that it lacks transaction support. However, I primarily use SQL Server, so I am not positive.

Answer (score 0):

The result attribute of cfquery can make this a whole lot simpler.  On an insert query, the recordcount property will tell you how many rows were inserted.  So you just need to do something like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="something" result="insertResult">
Insert into Registrations
 (Child_ID, Class_ID) 
 select distinct #Session.Child_ID#, #Class_ID#
 from registrations
 where (select count(*)
 from registrations
 where class_id = #Class_id#) <= #variable for max allowed goes here#
 </cfquery

<cfif insertResult.recordcount is 1>
code for successful registration
<cfelse>
code for full class
<cfif>
```

You'll have to use cfqueryparam in the subquery as a minimum.  If mysql allows it, also use it in the select clause.

Comment: Child_ID and Class_ID may not yet exist in Registrations. Also, a seat must be available in both classes for a registration to be inserted...if I understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: I'm probably missing something...it's always the details. How would your solution be implemented given both classes must be available before there can be an insert?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use MySQL transactional semantics to get this right.  `<CFLOCK>` is helpful, but it's not all you need.

First, you're going to need InnoDB.

Second, you're going to need a column in a table that contains "available beds" or whatever.  When that column's value hits zero, you're full.  If somebody cancels, you increment it.

Third, your SQL will need to do this:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 SELECT available_slots 
   FROM vacancy
  WHERE classname IN ('baskets', 'archery')
    FOR UPDATE;

  /* check the values of available_slots.  If all are > 0, 
     immediately do the sql to book the reservations.
     if any are <= 0, no vacancy; do ROLLBACK;
   */

 UPDATE available_slots 
    SET vacancy=vacancy-1 
  WHERE classname IN ('baskets', 'archery')


COMMIT;
```

The key concept here is that there's a single, identifiable, row for each scarce resource (in this case, available places in the archery and baskets classes). Locking the required rows for update while simultaneously checking their values is a simple and robust way to avoid over-committing  the scarce resource.

You could just have a one-row table, and lock the one row for every transaction.

Comment: How is that preferable to doing a count of registrations compared to the number of seats available for a given class?

Comment: I am not sure follow. How do those semantics prevent the classic read + write race condition? The count is decremented in a separate statement, so I am not sure I see how the `..for update` helps here. Can you explain?